Group and sort dataframe by min value
I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like the following:



Company
Make
Model
Speed
Time




GM
Chevy
Corvette
0
0


GM
Chevy
Camaro
10
0.05


GM
Chevy
Corvette
20
0.1


GM
Buick
Regal
100
8.8


GM
Buick
Regal
60
4.8



I'd like to be able to group this dataframe by Company, Make, and Model and both retrieve and sort by the start time for each of these groupings which would be defined as the min time. So in the example above I want to know that GM is the first company, within GM Chevy would be the first make (followed by Buick). Within Chevy, Corvette would be the first model (and so on).
I've started with df.groupby(["Company", "Make", "Model"])["Time"].min().sort_values() which gives me a dataframe with all the values grouped with a min time value. However, at this point I don't have the individual Time or Speed values anymore. I ultimately want something like this:
{
    "company_name": "GM",
    "start_time": 0,
    "makes": [
       {
           "name": "Chevy",
           "start_time": 0,
           "models": [
                {
                    "name": "Corvette",
                    "start_time": 0,
                    "time": [0, 0.1],
                    "speed": [0, 20]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Camaro",
                    "start_time": 0.05,
                    "time": [0.05],
                    "speed": [10]
                }
           ]
       },
       {
            "name": "Buick",
            "start_time": 4.8,
            "models": [
                {
                    "name": "Regal",
                    "start_time": 4.8,
                    "time": [4.8, 8.8],
                    "speed": [60, 100]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


use groupby.transform('min') in place of groupby.min()
